# vimscript documentation header @tag reference?

Tags: vimscript

Dumb question, but I can't find the answer in vim.org or Wikia - is there a reference for the @ tags (@Author, @License, ...) at the top of some of the vim scripts in the registry?  For example, [loremipsum.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2289):

```
" loremipsum.vim
" @Author:      Thomas Link (micathom AT gmail com?subject=[vim])
" @Website:     http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=4037
" @License:     GPL (see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt)
" @Created:     2008-07-10.
" @Last Change: 2008-07-11.
" @Revision:    66
" GetLatestVimScripts: 2289 0 loremipsum.vim
```

(Context: wondering how a script with two authors should be tagged).

Comment: Can you give an example? This sounds like [the meta tags in Javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#javadoctags).

Comment: In [`:help write-plugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write%2dplugin) some things are mentioned. The `@tag` notation is just done by some people who are used to it from other environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing official in Vim about using such meta-tags in comments. As Carpetsmoker says, it's likely a habit carried over by people usually working in other environments. I don't often use such tags myself, but they remind me of the [Javadoc meta tags](http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#javadoctags):

```
@author
{@code}
{@docRoot}
@deprecated
@exception
{@inheritDoc}
{@link}
...
```